# Live stream - multi-level word count using Apache Storm

Tags: twitter, apache-storm

I want find top geo-popular words based on twitter feeds using apache storm. I see many few examples which are working fine.

http://www.zdatainc.com/2014/07/real-time-streaming-apache-storm-apache-kafka/
https://github.com/davidkiss/storm-twitter-word-count

But I want to enhance the above solutions based on geo location. Many twitter status (tweets) come with geo location. I want to split the word count example into m x n matrix where m and n represents relative geo coordinates, example (3x4 = 30.x40.) latitude and longitude.

I want to split the input stream in to multiple counters based on Apache storm topology. The geo word counter bolt uniquely running for single coordinate cell (say x,y)

One solution that I got is, to register mxn number of bolts for every combination. But it's almost brute force. 
Second solution: Taking fieldsGrouping(x,y fields) is not working properly. I can see the same bolt running for same combination of x and y. I'm running in a local cluster.

Please suggest with some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, but if it isn't, try converting the latitude and longitude to a string, then concatenate them into a single field and use *that* field for the fieldsGrouping.